# How to change GROUPING value from 0/1 to no/yes?

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

How i can change column `Department ID Used` and `Job ID used` value from `0`/`1` to `no`/`yes`?

[image]

this my query:

```
SELECT d.department_name "department name", e.job_id "job title",
       SUM(e.salary) "monthly cost",
       GROUPING(d.department_id) "Department ID Used" ,
       GROUPING(e.job_id) "Job ID Used"
  FROM employees e
  JOIN departments d
    ON e.department_id=d.department_id
 GROUP BY CUBE(d.department_name, d.department_id, e.job_id)
ORDER BY d.department_name, e.job_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `CASE WHEN` clause to your `GROUPING BY` :

```
CASE WHEN GROUPING(d.department_id) = 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
```

`CASE` can be used in both SQL and PLSQL
whereas `DECODE` is specific to Oracle and can be used only in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

`DECODE(GROUPING(department_id),0,'no','yes')` with `GROUPING(d.department_id)`

and

`DECODE(GROUPING(e.job_id),0,'no','yes')` with `GROUPING(e.job_id)`